# How to do mutual recursion for class with imports?

Tags: javascript, class, recursion, circular-dependency, rollupjs

How can I deal with importing circular dependencies correctly?

base.ts

```
import * as all from './all'
export class Base {}
export class Container extends Base {
  parse(){
    console.log(all)
  }
}
```

all.ts

```
import { Base, Container } from './base';
export class A extends Base {}
export class B extends Container {}
```

main.ts

```
import { Container } from './base';
new Container().parse();
```

rollup generated code:

```
class A extends Base {
}
class B extends Container {
}
const all = /* @__PURE__ */ Object.freeze(/* @__PURE__ */ Object.defineProperty({
  __proto__: null,
  A,
  B
}, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }));
class Base {
}
class Container extends Base {
  parse() {
    console.log(all);
  }
}
new Container().parse();
```

Which puts `class B extends Container` before `class Container`, which of course fails.

Maybe, when such logic is necessary, there is no way to handle it gracefully, bundle has its own rule to choose which to put at first for circular dependency, and the order is very important where the circular dependent items can not be hoisted properly. i.e. `class` can not be hoisted in `class extends`

So i can provide two ugly/trick solution as last resort to make the code as least work

solution one:

```
  class A extends f() {}
  class C extends f() {}

  var _B; // only var can wrok, let will fail
  function f() {
    //make sure the return class with the same identity
    if (!_B) {
      _B = class B {
        static id = Math.random();
      };
    }
    return _B;
  }
```

The solution can work because `function` always be hoisted

Solution two:

```
import './all' //magic import make things work!
import { Container } from './base';
new Container().parse();
```

This can work because it enforce the dependency resolve order for circular dependency

Comment: I can guess how rollup handle circular import, it put treat the entry point as the start of and go through the dependency tree until the next time it come across the entry point. The problem is that it bundle the file in **reverse order**, it put the entry as the end of the bundle file! In terms of proper hoisting, it is OK, unfortunately,  hoisting is not work for **CLASS**

Comment: It has nothing to do with hoisting at all. Even with hoisting, once things refer to other things, they still need to be defined in the right order.

Comment: @deceze when there is a hoisting for class, the order is not that important, it will not report a error when is was bundled at the end of the file. That is way my original solution of the question is to wrap a class with function and it does work

Comment: @deceze It is very kind of your guys making the cause of the problem crystal clear! The conclusion is that bundler can not enforce the "correct" order when there is a circular import. From another point of view, the circular itself is highly dependent on hoisting. Unfortunately hoisting is not applicable to `class extends`. I do not think there is better solution than  wrapping the class with a function like me original question suggest

Comment: You should distribute your classes among files and import them in an order that doesn't create a circular dependency in the first place. These are always problematic, and different languages/systems fail on them in different ways.

Comment: @deceze So I got a serious trouble...

Comment: Please post the imports of *main.js*, the order you use there is the culprit

Comment: @Bergi just update the main.ts, it import base.ts which in turn import all.ts. so all.ts is bundled at the beginning in the generated file. And it breaks

Comment: Yes, you'd need to change *main.ts* to import *all.ts* (which in turn imports *base.ts*) first, so that *base.ts* is executed/bundled first. You can still import *base.ts* into *main.ts* afterwards.